# How to load OWL file from server machine

Tags: rdf, owl

I have loaded owl file from my local machine using following code

```
File file =new File("/home/gayathri/eclipse-workspace/Newwebapp/src/com/gayathri/steels2.owl");
```

Now i want to load it from my server machine. I don't know whether i should use same file to load or should i change to `IRI.create`? Please suggest me.

Comment: how would you specify a path to your server? It must be a URI which starts with whatever protocol you use. And then you can use `IRI.create`

Comment: `IRI IOR = IRI.create("http://serverip/AlloyOnto/steels3.owl");
o=man.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(IOR);` This will do the needfull right.

Comment: How can i retrieve them as triplets?

Comment: Retrieve what? It's also not clear which API you're using. OWL API for example is made for OWL, thus, the core entities are OWL axioms and not triples. If you want to work on the triple level, use Apache Jena or RDF4J

Comment: From the owl file i want to retrieve the triplets.

Comment: That's why I said, use Apache Jena or RDF4J for RDF. By the way, some OWL axioms might be represented by multiple RDF triples, keep that in mind.

Comment: @AKSW there are several implementations of OWL-API, some allows to work with triples as well. The statement 'thus, the core entities are OWL axioms and not triples' - is wrong. The desire to work with triples does not mean not to work with the OWL axioms and vice verse.

Comment: @ssz the original OWL API is made for OWL, nothing more nothing less. And the core "statements" are OWL axioms here. I said nothing wrong. I know that you're the dev of Ont-API, but that dos **not** make my statement wrong. OWL API is not an interface, it was always a full API. If people extend it, ok. but that's not "the OWL API". You implemented Ont-API against their interfaces and the Jena API, nevertheless that does not invalidate my statement. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Cat you can use Ont-API if you want, it implements both interfaces , the ones from Jena and OWL API. Their Github repo was moved now, things might be added to Jena in the future (pending discussion). That said, you got all you need. Use Ont-API, read their docs and then continue with your project